# how to read partial fragmented mp4 from buffer or stdin

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mp4box, fmp4

I am facing a weird challenge. I am still wondering if there's something wrong in my understanding of fragmented mp4 concepts.

I have a buffer stream of a video file, that I am streaming from AWS. Subsequently I am passing it to stdin and using ffmpeg to encode it.

What I want to achieve is if I skip 10000 initial bytes (say) from the source (which is S3 here), I still want to be able to encode the rest of the video in the buffer.

I tried to create a fragmented mp4 (10s) and split the file into chunks of 20MB and now if I try to play any of the chunks except the first one, it doesn't work. I am trying to understand how HLS or Dash uses fragments to jump directly to a part of the video.

I want to mimic basically the HLS player behaviour. Say, if I want to start streaming from S3 bucket from 200000 bytes, then I want to be able encode the video from there.